# Why do linters pick on useless escape character?

Tags: javascript, eslint, static-analysis

> Escaping non-special characters in strings, template literals, and regular expressions doesn't have any effect

Source: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-escape

But clearly this is wrong:

[image]

There's nothing to "fix" here; we all know this is a perfectly valid sequence of characters.

**Joking aside what's the rationale behind this?**

If even ESLint acknowledges that there's no harm then why bother? It may be useless if you only look at the end result (I know that the `\` character won't be printed out) but in a *"code is data"* context, this may be useful data when doing syntax analysis.

ESLint makes a judgment on what goes into the string, yet it won't budge with this code: (and that's pretty useless to me too)

```js
var x = 10;
var y = x + 0;
var z = y * 1;
```

Comment: Just log the string and you will see the problem

Comment: @Andreas I know what the “problem” is. that’s not the point.

Comment: The escape character is useless and will most likely change the content of the string in an unwanted way. So why should this not be objected to?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure the content is the concern here, `'\a'.length` is 1 not 2. I'd be fine if the error message was saying something like _"Did you mean to escape this character?"_ or _"You may need to escape \ as it won't be printed out"_.

Comment: @customcommander — Umm. So you can understand the purpose but you just wanted to complain that the error message isn't cuddly enough?

Comment: @customcommander this linting rule is helping programmers, it doesn't avoid any error, as there is no error. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Of I see code with a string like that, I need to think if it should have been "\\", anything that slows down another programmer reading your code is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the escape character isn't doing anything useful, what is it doing there?

Perhaps the writer of the code wanted a literal backslash character. The error draws attention to it so they can replace `\` with `\\`.

Perhaps they thought the next character needed escaping. This educates them otherwise.

Perhaps it is just a typo.

Since there is no *good* reason to have the `\` there, there can only be *bad* reasons. Some are more seriously bad than others, but the linter will draw attention to them.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I just wasn’t satisfied with the error message. Pull requests welcome indeed.

Comment: The error message is perfect though. I think you need to get mindset of a programming perfectionist to understand the purpose of linting rules like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Some linting rules are meant to make your code *perfect*.

You can escape characters if you want to, but sometimes it doesn't have any effect. If you still do that, you just put a meaningless character in your code, confusing other programmers and wasting 1 byte. Your code escapes the underscore character with `\_` sequence, whereas `\` doesn't do anything in that sequence.

This lint rule tells you about that. It's not the end of the world, but using that lint rule, you wanted to know.