# In JavaScript, string '\m' is fully equals to string 'm', why?

Tags: javascript, string

`console.log('\d' === 'd');   // true`

Character 'd' is not a special character, why javascript want to slice the escape notation. 
It's better to keep the escape notation in my view.

When I want to fully match string-'\d' using regular expression, it just impossible!
Taking the following code as an example.

```
console.log(RE.test('\d')); // it should log true 
console.log(RE.test('d'));  // it should log false
```

Unfortunately, you just cannot figure out a regular expression pattern.

Comment: `\d` is an escaped `d` character. There is no escape sequence for that, so you just get a literal `d` as string content. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - please focus on the actual problem you are trying to solve because escaping characters is surely not it.

Answer (score 6):

You have no reason to escape `d` in a string and JavaScript ignores it. If you need `\d` you need to escape the escape character: `\\d`.

See also [Why do linters pick on useless escape character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61782028/1244884)

Comment: So it just syntax of javascript language. There does not exist  a string like '\d' in javascript. Right?

Comment: @quanlili Strings can have `\d`, but string _literals_ cannot. If you want to use a `\ ` in a string literal, then you need to escape that backslash with another one. Or use the `String.raw` function: `let s = String.raw\`\d\``

Comment: Yes, I see. Much thx. I have not used String.raw `\d` before. It can output a raw String. Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

`\d` has a special meaning in *regular expressions* (a digit character), but also in *strings* (escaped 'd' character, which is exactly like `'d'`).

Any `/` creates an *escape sequence* in a string. Some are "useful" (`\n` === new line) and some arguably useless (`'\d' === 'd').

If you want the *regex*  `\d`, you could

1 - use a regex literal instead : `/\d/`

2 - escape the `\` in the string : `'\\d'`, so that the string containing the two characters `\` and `d` is correctly understood by Javascript.

Comment: ye， I got it. Much thx, bro.