# How do I validate a string using a regular expression with Ajv?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to validate a string(Phone number) with this regex **^+[0-9]{9,12}$**

but I get this error 
`... .pattern should match format "regex" ...`

I've been through the documentation at https://ajv.js.org etc. looked at examples etc. and tried a lot of variations, but can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

```
const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        users: {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    userReference: { type: 'string' },
                    phone: {
                        type: 'string'
                        , pattern: "^\+[0-9]{9,12}$" // If I remove this line, the model is seen as valid (and no errors)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    required: ['users'],
    errorMessage: { _: "One or more of the fields in the 'legacy' data path are incorrect." }
};

const schemaSample = {
    "users": [
        {
            "phone": "+25512345678", // should be valid
            "userReference": "AAA"
        },
        {
            "phone": "+5255 abc 12345678", // should be invalid
            "userReference": "BBB"
        }
    ]
};

var ajv = Ajv();
ajv.addSchema(schema, 'schema');

var valid = ajv.validate('schema', schemaSample);
if (valid) {
    console.log('Model is valid!');
} else {
    console.log('Model is invalid!');
}
```

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xnw2b9zL/4/ (Open Console / Debugger to see the full error)

Comment: You most probably forgot to double escape: `"\+"` should be `"\\+"`

Comment: I've literally spent HOURS on this damn thing!! Thanks that did the trick. If you post that as the answer I'll mark it as correct else I'll answer my own question later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL; DR**

Your regular expression *is* valid in a literal notation form but not in a constructor form where it is embedded into a string.

`"\+"` ❌ `"\\+"` ✅

When embedding a regular expression into a string, double check your escape characters!

**Why?**

Because useless escape characters will be ignored. If it wasn't for constructing a regular expression you have no reason to escape a `'+'` character:

```js
"\+" === "+"
//=> true
```

The error you saw had nothing to do with the data, it was in the construction of the schema. As you can see here:

```js
const ajv = new Ajv;

try {
  ajv.compile({type: 'string' , pattern: '^\+[0-9]{9,12}$'});
} catch (e) {
  console.log(`ERR! ${e.message}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.12.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

But digging deeper, it has nothing to do with Ajv either. Ajv does mention:

> Ajv uses new RegExp(value) to create the regular expression that will be used to test data.

See https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html#pattern

So what does it mean to do `new RegExp("\+")`? Let's find out:

```js
// similar error because "\+" and "+" are the same string
try { new RegExp("\+") } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
try { new RegExp("+") } catch (e) { console.log(e.message) }
```

**Related**

- [Why do linters pick on useless escape character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61782028/1244884)

Comment: One simple trick you can use is RegExp's toString `/(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$)/.toString().slice(1,-1)` will automatically escape it for you. Slice allows use directly because the '/' are interpreted literally

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is wrongly stringified. To avoid mistakes you can use [native Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as follow:

```js
{
  type: 'string', 
  pattern: /^\+[0-9]{9,12}$/.toString().slice(1, -1)
}
```

Note that `.slice(1, -1)` removes the first and last characters which are the regexp delimiters and should not be included in the `RegExp` constructor.

```
/test/.toString() // "/test/"
/test/.toString().slice(1, -1) // "test"
new RegExp(/test/.toString().slice(1, -1)) // /test/
```

You also cannot use any flag as they have to be provided as a [separate argument to the RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#syntax).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @customcommander comment.

The documentation about [format](https://tsed.io/api/common/jsonschema/decorators/Format.html#overview) state that :

> regex: tests whether a string is a valid regular expression by passing
>   it to RegExp constructor.

---

In javascript when you declare a string the backslashes will be interpreted. That's why you need to double the backslashes.

If you don't, what you are passing to Avg and in fine to `new RegExp(...)` is the string `"^+[0-9]{9,12}$"`, which is an incorrect RegExp.

[image]

---

PS: nice dog

Comment: I thought my regex was formatted correctly, as I entered it into regex101 and generated javascript for it, and it generated /^\+[0-9]{9,12}$/gm, but I now see it's not generated in a string. So never thought to double check my regex.